# Creating multistore configurable products

Tags: configurable-product, multistore, language

I have a few configurable products created with XML import that are presents on 5 stores with different language, and color as super attribute.

When the simple products are linked to the configurable is there any way to have different label color for each language?

And a way to change the name of the confifurable product per store? I have tried with setStore() before product loading, after loading, by just saving the name, even adding entry in the database...

Any help will be fully appreciate. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify the attribute name (in this case color) translation by configuring the attributes label options.

In admin goto catalog -> attributes -> manage attributes and select your attribute, i.e. color. Then add the translations for each of your stores languages as shown below

[image]

You can also edit the attribute name for each store view via the configurable product associated products Super product attributes configuration.

Comment: Oh yes, you are totally right, now I just need to change the XML structure! Any clue on name per store for configurable product?